# Functions can be represented by several formats or they are immutable?

Tags: functions

I have discussed about representations of functions with a colleague. I will show an example to support what I believe first, after the opinion of my colleague.
Given two functions and their DOMs

$f(x)=\frac{x-3}{x^3-3x^2+5x-15} \qquad \quad\operatorname{Dom}f(x)= \lbrace x \in R \mid x \neq 3\rbrace \\ $

and

$g(x)=\frac1{x^2+5}\qquad \qquad \qquad \operatorname{Dom}g(x)= \lbrace x \in R \rbrace \\$

As we can observe, considering their DOMs:

$f(3) \;  \nexists\qquad$ in the other hand $\qquad g(3) \;  \exists \\$

The fact is they can be equalized:

$$f(x)=\frac{x-3}{x^3-3x^2+5x-15}=\frac{x-3}{(x-3)(x^2+5)}=\frac1{x^2+5}=g(x)$$

Getting at this point, I believe that f(x) actually is another notation of g(x) and, as they are the same function, Dom g(x) must be adopted as the function DOM, as f(3) exists!

My colleague believes those functions are not equal at all, so f(3) still doesn't exist and the fact of they be equalized doesn't change function's originally adopted properties.

As we want an agreement, I will appreciate comments to help us to get it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is the data of : a domain $X$, a codomain $Y$, and the graph $\Gamma\subset X\times Y$. So technically $f$ and $g$ are not equal because they don't have the same domain the way you defined them.

This being said, they can be thought of as the same function for all practical purposes since $g$ is uniquely defined by $f$ as its continuous extension (for instance).

Answer (score 2):

$f$ and $g$ are different functions, period. The specific relation that occurs here is that $f$ has a **removable discontinuity** at $x=3$ and that $g$ is the **continuous extension** of $f$ (into $x=3$).

Answer (score 0):

The functions you are using as a example are not equal, as their domain is distinct.

There is not much too be said about that, since this comes from the definition of equality, but we can explore what this means from a set-theoretic point of view, since set theory is widely accepted as an acceptable formalization of usual math.

In set theory, functions are sets formed by pairs of elements/image. Thus $g$ contains the pair $(3, 1/14)$ while $f$ does not. Since two sets are equal if and only if they contain the same elements, $f$ is not equal to $g$.